# float.__str__ behaves differently in python 2 and 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

In `python 2.7`

```
In [83]: (2.01909 * 100000).__str__()
Out[83]: '201909.0'
```

In `python 3.6`

```
In [47]: (2.01909 * 100000).__str__()
Out[47]: '201908.99999999997'
```

Is this expected or known difference?

Can we make them consistent?

Comment: @Poojan what do you mean? I just run the same code in two different python version

Comment: I also had the same problem with chaquopy running on Android using python 3.6.5. But when i tried the same thing which is printing 3.9 my pc had no problem with python 3.7